# Jar issues with JAXB Implementation

Tags: java, jboss, jaxb, docx4j

Im trying to manipulate document using docx4j library and as a standalone , the program worked fine but when i deployed it in jBoss, it is giving below error

I have checked and found that jaxb-impl.jar already exists in jboss classpath

```
10:44:28,118 INFO  [stdout] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-9080-5) 2015-08-30 10:44:28,118 ERROR [http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-9080-5] [org.docx4j.jaxb.Context] - PANIC! No suitable JAXB implementation available

10:44:28,118 ERROR [stderr] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-9080-5) javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/C:/Documentum/jboss7.1.1/modules/javax/xml/bind/api/main/jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class to jar:file:/C:/Documentum/java64/1.7.0_17/jre/lib/rt.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class.  Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.
10:44:28,133 ERROR [stderr] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-9080-5)  - with linked exception:
10:44:28,133 ERROR [stderr] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-9080-5) [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/C:/Documentum/jboss7.1.1/modules/javax/xml/bind/api/main/jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class to jar:file:/C:/Documentum/java64/1.7.0_17/jre/lib/rt.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class.  Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.]
10:44:28,133 ERROR [stderr] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-9080-5)  - with linked exception:
10:44:28,133 ERROR [stderr] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-9080-5) [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/C:/Documentum/jboss7.1.1/modules/javax/xml/bind/api/main/jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class to jar:file:/C:/Documentum/java64/1.7.0_17/jre/lib/rt.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class.  Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.
10:44:28,133 ERROR [stderr] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-9080-5)  - with linked exception:
10:44:28,133 ERROR [stderr] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-9080-5) [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/C:/Documentum/jboss7.1.1/modules/javax/xml/bind/api/main/jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class to jar:file:/C:/Documentum/java64/1.7.0_17/jre/lib/rt.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class.  Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.]]
```

Below is jBoss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <!-- Make sub deployments isolated by default, so they cannot see each others classes without a Class-Path entry -->
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>

    <!-- This corresponds to the top level deployment, for bpm.ear -->
    <!-- This is the top level ear module, which contains all the classes in the EAR's lib folder     -->
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
            <module name="javax.jms.api"/>
            <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        </exclusions>
        <!-- Castor API we use in parsing XML schemas depends on xerces parser -->
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.xerces" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
    <!-- This corresponds to the bpm.war's module -->
    <sub-deployment name="bpm.war">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
            <module name="javax.jms.api"/>
            <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>


</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Looks like you're using JBoss 7.1.1?  Did you follow http://www.docx4java.org/forums/jboss-f29/jboss-7-config-t1678.html

Comment: @JasonPlutext i have copied jaxb implementation jars inside the jBoss lib but for some reason it still goves error.Do you think its related to multiple copied of Jaxb jar files ?

Comment: @JasonPlutext Any idea about this

Comment: Per the link I gave above, what does you WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml contain?  Please paste it into your question above.

Comment: @JasonPlutext Added the jboss-deployment-structure.xml